# Problema con .pack() y tkinter.Frame con width y height establecidos: Al posicionar widget dentro el frame desaparece

Tags: python, tkinter

Estoy tratando de poner un widget `Button` dentro de un `Frame` pero al hacerlo el frame deja de estar, solo esta el botón encima del canvas, ¿Por qué el widget anula el frame?.

Adjunto aquí mi código:

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk

class Paint(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self,root = None):
        super().__init__(root)

        self.root = root
        self.root.title("Paint")
        self.root.geometry("+250+10")
        self.create_widgets()

    def create_widgets(self):


        self.Opciones = tk.Frame(self.root,bg="skyblue",width=800,height=60)
        self.Opciones.pack(side=tk.TOP)


        self.hoja = tk.Canvas(self.root,bg = "white",width = 800,height = 600)
        self.hoja.pack()

        self.Button = ttk.Style()
        self.Button.configure("Button.TButton",selectforeground = "white",fg="black",bg="white",font=("Arial",12),height=1)

        self.Colores = ttk.Button(self.Opciones,style="Button.TButton",text="Colores",width=7)
        self.Colores.pack()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    root = tk.Tk()
    App = Paint(root = root)
    App.mainloop()
```

Si comentamos estas 2 lineas:

```
self.Colores = ttk.Button(self.Opciones,style="Button.TButton",text="Colores",width=7)
self.Colores.pack()
```

Si aparece correctamente el frame, lo que quiero es que el botón este dentro del frame a la izquierda, ¿cómo podría lograrlo?

Comment: Te recomiendo utilizar `.grid` para darle posición a tu botón. ej: `self.Colores.grid(row=0, column=0)`, dependiendo que posición quieres y puedes ponerle padding.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Por defecto, tanto `grid` como `pack` intentan ajustar el tamaño del widget para que se ajuste al mínimo necesario para contener a los widgets del que es padre, es lo que se conoce como "geometry propagation".

Si no deseas éste comportamiento, debes indicarle al administrador de geometría que el `Frame` debe ocupar todo el espacio que tiene asignado sin importar el tamaño de sus widgets, en caso contrario intentará que ocupe lo menos posible, que en este caso es justo el tamaño que tiene su único widget, el botón, ignorando los parámetros `width` y `height`.

No es que el `Frame` desaparezca, es que tiene el mismo tamaño justo que el botón que contiene, por lo que queda completamente superpuesto por él.

Para evitar esto usa el método `pack_propagate` pasando `0` o `False` como argumento, dado que posicionas el botón con `pack`:

```
self.opciones = tk.Frame(self.root, bg="skyblue", width=800, height=60)
self.opciones.pack(side=tk.TOP)
self.opciones.pack_propagate(0)
```

Si se usar `.grid` como administrador de geometría, se debe usar su homólogo:

```
self.opciones = tk.Frame(self.root, bg="skyblue", width=800, height=60)
self.opciones.grid(row=0, column=0)
self.opciones.grid_propagate(0)
```

---

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk



class Paint(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self,root = None):
        super().__init__(root)

        self.root = root
        self.root.title("Paint")
        self.root.geometry("+250+10")
        self.create_widgets()

    def create_widgets(self):
        self.opciones = tk.Frame(self.root, bg="skyblue", width=800, height=60)
        self.opciones.pack(side=tk.TOP)
        self.opciones.pack_propagate(0)


        self.hoja = tk.Canvas(self.root, bg="white", width=800, height=600)
        self.hoja.pack()

        self.button = ttk.Style()
        self.button.configure("Button.TButton", selectforeground="white",
            fg="black", bg="white", font=("Arial",12), height=1
            )

        self.colores = ttk.Button(self.opciones, style="Button.TButton",
            text="Colores", width=7
            )
        self.colores.pack()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    root = tk.Tk()
    app = Paint(root=root)
    app.mainloop()
```

Si quieres centrar el botón también  en `Y`, posiblemente `place` sea mejor opción en este caso:

```
import tkinter as tk
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk



class Paint(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self,root = None):
        super().__init__(root)

        self.root = root
        self.root.title("Paint")
        self.root.geometry("+250+10")
        self.create_widgets()

    def create_widgets(self):
        self.opciones = tk.Frame(self.root, bg="skyblue", width=800, height=60)
        self.opciones.pack(side=tk.TOP)


        self.hoja = tk.Canvas(self.root, bg="white", width=800, height=600)
        self.hoja.pack()

        self.button = ttk.Style()
        self.button.configure("Button.TButton", selectforeground="white",
            fg="black", bg="white", font=("Arial",12), height=1
            )

        self.colores = ttk.Button(self.opciones, style="Button.TButton",
            text="Colores", width=7
            )
        self.colores.place(relx=0.5, rely=0.5, anchor=tk.CENTER)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    root = tk.Tk()
    app = Paint(root=root)
    app.mainloop()
```